# Cannot copy html response using findElement Selenium - Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to copy the html response content of the webpage https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w?pageno=1&strCat=-1&strPrevDate=20220204&strScrip=&strSearch=P&strToDate=20220204&strType=C
in selenium using a webelement. I used 'Table' in findElement but it throws error as below.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

How can I copy the html response into a java variable using selenium or any other tool?

Below is the code:

```
public void launchBrowser() 
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/vamsi/selenium-java-4.1.0/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w?pageno=1&strCat=-1&strPrevDate=20220204&strScrip=&strSearch=P&strToDate=20220204&strType=C");
WebElement p = driver.findElement(By.name("Table"));        
}
```

Comment: The page is not loading by the time you code is executed. Add some wait condition and try it. 


WebElement recoverText =  waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("pre[id='something'] code")));
String textStr = recoverText.getAttribute("innerText");

Answer (score 0):

The page source response is not HTML, it's json string.

So it's not possible to locate any element.

However, it's possible to get the response content.

```java
String source = driver.getPageSource();
```

Besides, it's possible to parse data with:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Map<String,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(source, HashMap.class);

Object tableData = result.get("Table"); //Looks like it's List Object
```

this dependency required:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.1